# Mysql DELETE query the row first

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user_id FROM post WHERE user_id=:user_id && post_id=:post_id

if ($row==1){
DELETE FROM post WHERE user_id=:user_id && post_id=:post_id LIMIT 1
}
```

I have a mysql DELETE question.

Do I need to query to find out the if the row is exit and run the DELETE query after, or I can just run DELETE query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just run the query. If the WHERE clause fails, it will simply delete "0" rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the confirmation, then you are OK. If you do, then you can obtain affected rows count

Answer (score 0):

No need to use if condition. if the row is empty SQL Engine automatically will stop